# making C wrapper from asm of nasm

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

This was a C program in the beginning then converted to nasm
 but no luck trying to put into shellcode format. (segment fault)

```
global main

extern printf

SECTION .text   align=4

main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, L_001
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret

SECTION .data   align=4

SECTION .bss    align=4

SECTION .rodata

L_001:
        db 48H, 65H, 6CH, 6CH, 6FH, 20H, 74H, 68H
        db 65H, 72H, 65H, 00H
```

This was written on a x86_64 platform of CentOS

C wrapper program(shellcode format)

`char code[] = "\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x74\x68\x65\x72\x65\x00";`

`int main(int argc, char **argv)`
`{
    (*(void(*)())code)();`

`return 0;
}`

Comment: C wrapper : `int main() { printf ("Hello there"); return 0;}`

Comment: My answer was in jest, but it really is unclear what you are asking, What do you mean by C wrapper? Inline assembly? make it available to be called from C? Very hard to tell.

Comment: Specifying different sections for stuff that is going to be put in a shellcode doesn't make any sense. Also,  you should use rip-addressing to refer to your data, and put the result in an appropriately sized register.